# Calculation running out of time

Tags: android, time

In my Android application I use the follow function. But I found out that when `time` is greater than 16777215 (0xFFFFFF) the calculation takes to much time and is incremented every 2 seconds instead of 1.

Is there a way to optimize the code below so it can handle numbers larger than 0xFFFFFF in time?

```
/**
 * Sets the time wheels to the right time.
 * @param time in seconds
 * @param animation for enableing and disabling animation
 */
private void setTime(float time, boolean animation) {        
    int days;
    int hours;
    int mins;
    int secs;

    days = (int) (time / (3600*24));
    hours = (int)(time / 3600);
    time = time % 3600;
    mins = (int) (time / 60);
    time = time % 60;
    secs = (int) time;

    if(days >= 1){
        getWheel(R.id.time4).setCurrentItem(days, animation);
    } else {
        getWheel(R.id.time4).setCurrentItem(0, animation);
    }

    if(hours >= 1){
        getWheel(R.id.time3).setCurrentItem(hours, animation);
    } else {
        getWheel(R.id.time3).setCurrentItem(0, animation);
    }

    if(mins >= 1){
        getWheel(R.id.time2).setCurrentItem(mins, animation);
    } else {
        getWheel(R.id.time2).setCurrentItem(0, animation);
    }

    if(secs >= 1){
        getWheel(R.id.time1).setCurrentItem(secs, animation);
    } else {
        getWheel(R.id.time1).setCurrentItem(0, animation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html
A `Time` object maybe do the trick?

You may are exceeding the `float` datatype, you should use `long` in this case.

This http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/Time.html#Time%28long%29 constructor is using `long`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a double, or long instead of float to speed up the calculation.

If you keep the days, hours, mins, and secs variables as the same type as time you can get rid of the casts also.